# Python Tkinter Блокировка окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Как раскрыть окно Tkinter (zoomed, fullscreen, deiconify не подходит). 
Проблема такая, мне нужно сделать окно, с которого нельзя выйти (это я  реализовал), но в котором можно запустить какое-то приложение и с ним работать, после закрытия этого приложения оставить первоначальную программу как она и была в фоне (проблема в том что она после закрытия второстпенной программы сворачивается почему-то)

Comment: Задайте более конкретный вопрос. Как минимум добавьте более подробное описание что вы сделали с окном и каким образом его раскрыть(растянуть на весь экран или же просто открыть свернутое окно)

Comment: Добавил больше описания